# Closing Fancybox 3 on a mobile device

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

Using fancybox on desktop, it closes when clicked outside the content. Using it on a mobile device, it closes ONLY when the content is slided up or down (it doesn't react to clicking outside the content).

Is it possible (and how) to close fancybox on a mobile device just by clicking outside the content ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fancyBox has different "click event" for mobile devices and you can customize them using "mobile" option, for example:

```
mobile : {
    clickContent : "close",
    clickSlide : "close"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Somehow I didn't fully understand those options - I thought that clickOutside should have been enough...

Comment: truly blessed age we live in... I googled "fancybox close on click outside mobile" and solved my problem in 10 seconds.

Comment: June 2020 works for me but I have this delay - the image doesn't close immediately (its about a second of waiting)... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This example try it :

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  clickContent : function( current, event ) {
    return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : 'close';
  }
});
```

and this link try it : 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEKmoB

Comment: Interesting... thank you. Your example (your link) works perfectly, while my demo doesn't: http://mikasbinkis.lt/xp/. Could you give me any tips on what could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Umm.... sorry to bother you, but did you include a link? Cause I can't see one...

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me using Fancybox 3.5.7 modifying the mobile section of the original source code in the mobile section:

```
mobile: {
                preventCaptionOverlap: !1,
                idleTime: !1,
                clickContent: function (t, e) {
                    return "image" === t.type && "close";
                },
                clickSlide: function (t, e) {
                    return "image" === t.type && "close";
                },
```

Someone asked about the delay above. The delay happens on click to understand if there will be a double click. Time is needed to see if another click comes in, if not, then the image closes. So if you (as in my example) remove the doubleclick functionality (dblclickContent & dblclickSlide) this removes that delay issue.